# How I can solve this problem? Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'o.orders' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

```
USE sql_store;

SELECT
    o.orders,
    c.first_name
FROM orders o
NATURAL JOIN customers c
```

I get an error message and I can not solve it

Comment: What columns do you have in your `orders` table? I bet that `orders` isn't one of them.

Comment: it's probably something like `o.order_id` or `o.order_number`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question title. Check your orders table, you don't have  column order there and with given information, we cannot guess something else